# Routing when nested components are used on AppComponent

Tags: angular2-routing, angular2-directives

I am fairly new to Angular 2 and having a problem with Routing. I have just started to explore the Routing. I will explain the structure and what I have achieved so far,

app.router.ts

```
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core'
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router'

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LoginComponent } from "../app/login/login.component"

export const router: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: LoginComponent },
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent }, 
    { path: 'dashboard', component: AppComponent }
];

export const routes:  ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(router);
```

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import {UiSwitchModule} from 'angular2-ui-switch'

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AllReportsComponent } from "../app/all-reports/all-reports.component"
import { AvailableReportsComponent } from "../app/available-reports/available-reports.component"
import { NextReportsComponent } from "../app/next-reports/next-reports.component"
import { UrlsComponent } from "../app/urls/urls.component"
import { LoginComponent } from "../app/login/login.component"
import { TaskApi } from "../app/api/TaskApi"

import { routes } from "../app/app.router"

@NgModule({
    imports: [ 
        BrowserModule, 
        FormsModule, 
        UiSwitchModule,
        HttpModule,
        routes
    ],
    declarations: [ 
        AppComponent, 
        AllReportsComponent, 
        AvailableReportsComponent, 
        NextReportsComponent,
        UrlsComponent, 
        LoginComponent        
        ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule {

}
```

app.html

```
   <div>
        <all-reports></all-reports>
       <available-reports></available-reports>
        <next-reports></next-reports>
        <urls></urls>
   </div>
```

app.component.ts (very simple)

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core"

@Component({
    templateUrl: '../app/app.html'
})

export class AppComponent {

}
```

and login.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { TaskApi } from '../api/TaskApi';
import * as models from '../model/models';

@Component({

    styleUrls: ['/app/css/login.css'],
    templateUrl: '../../app/login/login.html',
    providers: [TaskApi]
})
```

export class LoginComponent {

}

Now it can be seen that I am using multiple directives on app.html and all the respective components are working fine.

The problem I am facing is when I introduce Routing then I am able to understand where to use "router-outlet". I have used it on Index.html but it does not work and gives error about ng-component. So to just test around I have used following in Index.html,

```
<body>   
    <base href="/"> 
    <ng-component></ng-component>
</body>
```

After I do this then my AppComponent is displayed by default where the LoginComponent should be displayed by default. On console, It also gives me error "Error: Cannot find primary outlet to load 'LoginComponent'"

Kindly guide me if I am using 4 directives on App.html as mentioned above then in that case how the routing will work. To summarize, I want to display Login page on localhost:3009/login and localhost:3009 and I want to display Home page (app.html) in localhost:3009/dashboard and app.html is using 4 directives to display 4 child components on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Angular Routing

> Since Angular is single page application the routing functionality
>   helps to display different view in single page.

#### How to use router to change view?

since **app.component.html** is main view for most user. Iam also consider app.component.html as main view.

Router-outlet

```
  Router-outer helps to load the change in our angular application.
```

#### app.component.html

```html
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Set AppComponent Default page as router-outlet and create new Dashboard.component.html in your main view.

#### router.ts

```html
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core'
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router'

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard.component';
import { LoginComponent } from "../app/login/login.component"

export const router: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: LoginComponent },
    { path: 'login', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full' }, 
    { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent }
];

export const routes:  ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(router);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't thought to add a new component and use App component as base for other components. I was trying to use App Component for itself and others.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that there is no 'router-outlet', so angular doesn't understand where to display the view.

**The 'router-outlet' directive marks where the router displays a view.**

In your code, since in app.component.ts you are using app.html so you should use `<router-outlet> </router-outlet>` in that HTML file.

Your app.html file should look like this:

```
<router-outlet> </router-outlet>
```

These below things should not be used in the app component HTML file. They should be used in their the corresponding components.

```
   <all-reports></all-reports>
   <available-reports></available-reports>
   <next-reports></next-reports>
   <urls></urls>
```

For further understanding, please refer to the official documentation of Angular2. They have explained it pretty well here https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html